# jquery file upload (sorting)

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload, can anyone help me to sort the files based on latest(top) to oldest (bottom). This script sort the files based on alphabets by default.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example response of the JSON, you need to configure a few things on the server-side to add a 'date_created' property with its timestamp **if you want to do the sorting on the client-side.**

```
{"files": [
  {
    "name": "picture1.jpg",
    "size": 902604,
    "url": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture1.jpg",
    "thumbnailUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/thumbnail\/picture1.jpg",
    // add created_date property
    "date_created": "some date value you want to use",
    "deleteUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture1.jpg",
    "deleteType": "DELETE"
  },
  {
    "name": "picture2.jpg",
    "size": 841946,
    "url": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture2.jpg",
    "thumbnailUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/thumbnail\/picture2.jpg",
    // add date_created property to the JSON
    "date_created": "some date value you want to use",
    "deleteUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture2.jpg",
    "deleteType": "DELETE"
  }
]}
```

If you want to sort the data BEFORE it is given to the client-side, you must look into the file `./lib/uploadhandler.js` between lines 37-49 and retrieve the created date and add a sorting function for the array '`files`'. **NOTE: this solution is for nodejs!**  I do not know what server-side language you are using, but the result would be very similar.